# Tikz nodes with pattern ignoring z-order/fill

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I'm trying to draw overlapping circles with patterns aka hatches. Overlapping circles are meant to **hide underlying circles**. This is the way it usually works **without patterns**, but as soon as I add patterns, the value for `fill` seems to be completely ignored.

Is there any way to use `patterns` **with** `fill`? Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{%
    shapes.misc,    % additional shapes, such as rounded rectangles
    positioning,    % advanced positioning
    patterns,       % hatches etc
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    roundnode/.style={circle, draw=black, fill=yellow!20, thick, inner sep=0em, opacity=1, fill opacity=1, draw opacity=1, font=\small},
    ]
    
    \node[roundnode, minimum size=15mm] (nodeA) at (1, 0) {A};
    \node[roundnode, minimum size=15mm, fill=red!20, pattern=north west lines, pattern color=gray] (nodeB) at (2, 0) {B};
    
    \node[roundnode, minimum size=15mm] (nodeC) at (2, 1) {C};
    \node[roundnode, minimum size=15mm, pattern=north east lines, pattern color=gray] (nodeD) at (2, -1) {D};
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, use `postaction`.

Comment: Thanks! Unluckily I have no idea how to use `postaction` to do this. Could you please tell me how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `postaction` to achieve the desired effect. Please note also that there is `patterns.meta` which is an arguably more convenient way to add pattern (but you will still need a `postaction` or declare a filled pattern).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{%
    shapes.misc,    % additional shapes, such as rounded rectangles
    positioning,    % advanced positioning
    patterns,       % hatches etc
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    roundnode/.style={circle, draw=black, fill=yellow!20, thick, inner sep=0em, opacity=1, fill opacity=1, draw opacity=1, font=\small},
    ]
    
    \node[roundnode, minimum size=15mm] (nodeA) at (1, 0) {A};
    \node[roundnode, minimum size=15mm, fill=red!20, 
        postaction={pattern=north west lines, pattern color=gray}] (nodeB) at (2, 0) {B};
    
    \node[roundnode, minimum size=15mm] (nodeC) at (2, 1) {C};
    \node[roundnode, minimum size=15mm, 
        postaction={pattern=north east lines, pattern color=gray}] (nodeD) at (2, -1) {D};
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! This is working like a charm. Already switched to `patterns.meta`, but have rarely seen this lib here on stackexchange, thus thought the bare `patterns` lib might be better known...